# ERROR: column "USA" does not exist postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, string-constant

I am new to posrgresql. I created a table called games where I have three columns: country, games, year. I am trying to insert some data to it using this code:

insert into games
values("USA", "Baseball", 2012),
("China", "Wrestling", 2011),
("England", "Cricket", 2015),
("India", "Cricket", 2011),
("USA", "Football", 2018),
("Spain", "Football", 2014),
("China", "Basketball", 2019),
("Italy", "Football", 2017);

I am getting this error:
ERROR:  column "USA" does not exist
LINE 2: values("USA", "Baseball", 2012),

What is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to change double quotes to a single one. Double quotes are for names of tables or fields. The single quotes are for string constants. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6eb43c370a391a33c16acc925c9e5084

Comment: Also, it's strongly suggested that you name the columns while inserting, as in `insert into games (country, sport, year) values('USA', 'Baseball', 2012), ...`.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS